# Why "Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Alamofire' is correct."?

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, alamofire

"No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.Alamofire' is correct." -- This error occur for me when I am trying to upload the build to iTunes connect.

I have tried the following solutions,

1. Created new provisioning profile and created as another new app in iTunes
2. Renamed the bundle id for Alamofire
3. Double checked the bundle id in app with the one in iTunes connect
4. Removed and reinstalled pod

but still it's not working.

I have found lot of answers and suggestions for this in stack overflow.But nothing helped me..

Anyone has the solution to fix this.

Comment: Why the heck did you renamed bundle ID for Alamofire?

Comment: I know it is not the correct one, still I found it as one suggestion in stack overflow, anyway it'll not help. Let me know if you had solution.

Comment: Install pod deintegrate -> Use Pod deintegrate on the project, than Pod install and then try to build the project again and hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: You can find it in here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no..@DominikBucher

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I haven't worked on this project for long time.. Now, due to the need I started to work and again got the same issue. when I started listing the possibilities of this issue..I found where i was wrong. I missed to add "Bundle OS Type code - APPL" in app's info.plist.

Actually few seconds work, due to my carelessness I resolved it after a month.

Thank you for your suggestion @Dominik Bucher

Answer (score 2):

This got me on the right track, in my plist file the line causing this was:

```
<string>APPL    </string>
```

removing the trailing spaces to :

```
<string>APPL</string>
```

fixed it, I had been editing other parts of the plist manually.... no hablo Trim() Xcode?

Comment: My plist was missing the CFBundlePackageType completely causing similar error. Adding the above APPL string entry fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you check all your certificates. I went through the same thing and it only worked after I deleted/revoked all my certificates and redid them. Good Luck!